# Why am I getting an error in Windows 7 when restoring from hibernation?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I am getting the following error when restoring from hibernation in Windows 7 RTM.  It seems to be happening more often.  My laptop is a Dell Latitude D520.

```
Your computer can't come out of hibernation.
Status: 0xc000009a
Info: A fatal error occurred processing the restoration data.
File: \hiberfil.sys
```

Comment: If it is the battery, then the hibernation image is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually fairly convinced now that this had to do with my battery. It doesn't fit that snugly, and I believe I may have been accidentally disconnecting it when putting it in my laptop case. Now, I wait until the computer powers down before putting the laptop away, and I have not seen the problem since.

Answer (score 4):

defragment hiberfil.sys:

[disable hibernation](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/12/how-to-enable-or-disable-hibernate-in-windows-7/), defragment the drive and then re-enable hibernation. now you'll have a contigeous file "hiberfil.sys"

Comment: Hmm...this sounds suspect.  Why would the OS allow hiberfil.sys to become fragmented if it meant that restoring from it would fail...?

Comment: I have the same problem on an SSD. And SSD cannot or should not be defragmented.

Answer (score 2):

through personal experience, I know this only works for windows 7 but will probably work for vista and xp to

Run command prompt as administrator and type in

powercfg -h off

after that reboot the computee and open up command prompt again (same as above) and type

powercfg -h on

You should now be able to hibernate the computer and boot from hibernation without receiving the error message

Answer (score 0):

If this problem doesn't let you reboot the computer, use your O/S CD to boot the O/S, or if that fails you can still perform a repair install on your current OS.

Note that a repair will not remove any of your personal data but will simply replace the OS System files to fix any corruptions.

If you can reboot, follow Molly's advice.

Comment: You can choose to skip restoring the hibernation file and boot normally (since Vista). If you reboot once while its restoring Windows will provide a menu asking if you want to delete it and boot normal or attempt to restore again. You can actually interrupt the Windows 7 restore by pressing the space bar while its loading!

Comment: @Joshua : nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether this is a battery issue or not...

Remove the battery and leave the laptop plugged in to AC power.  If the laptop still displays your same error above, your hiberfil.sys may be corrupt - I've run into this a few times.

Disable Hibernation, delete the hiberfil.sys file and restart the machine.  Run CCleaner (www.ccleaner.com/download/downloading), defrag the drive and restart again.  Now, re-enable Hibernation.  Chances are this will correct the issue.